# Bool type usage for Swift class and Objective - c same time

Tags: swift, objective-c

I have a swift model class like this;

`class Test: NSObject, Codable { var property: Bool? }`

i want to use this bool type in swift class and objective - c at the same time. But the problem is I can't use Bool type in objective - c, if I replace bool type with NSNumber and use in objective - c than I'm having Test class codable error since NSNumber is not codable data type. What is the best way to use bool type in swift and objective - c same time.

Comment: Would add an extension with a dynamic property help? Something like this `var propertyForObjc: NSNumber? { self.property }`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `Bool` is a value type and Obj-C doesn't support optional value types. Obj-C only supports nullability for reference types, by representing null values with a null pointer.

There are multiple workarounds for this problem, such as

1. Declare `property` as `NSNumber` and implement the `Codable` conformance manually
2. Make `Test` a pure-Swift type and create a separate Obj-C bridge type (similar to how Foundations bridges between Swift and Obj-C types, such as `String` and `NSString` or `Array` and `NSArray`).

I'd suggest point 2, since `Codable` is only usable from Swift, so there's no point in exposing a `Codable` conformant type to Obj-C, because you can only encode/decode it in Swift anyways. This also means that you can use any Swift features in your type, you don't need to restrict yourself to Obj-C compatible types and language features. Moreover, if you get to the point where you can remove the access from Obj-C, you can simply delete your bridge type and won't have to modify your pure Swift type.

Here's a simple example of an Obj-C bridge for `Test`:

```
@objc class TestBridge: NSObject {
  @objc var property: NSNumber? {
    get {
      wrapped.property as NSNumber?
    }

    set {
      wrapped.property = newValue?.boolValue
    }
  }

  let wrapped: Test

  @objc init(property: NSNumber?) {
    self.wrapped = Test(property: property?.boolValue)
  }
}
```

And the pure-Swift `Test` class:

```
class Test: Codable {
  var property: Bool?

  init(property: Bool?) {
    self.property = property
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for detailed explanation. Second option is make sense but I have a lot of model class so its gonna be long process seems like :)

Comment: @Begbie do you actually need to access all of your model classes from Obj-C? You can extend Obj-C classes from Swift and access pure Swift methods/types from these extensions. Forward declaration is also a very valuable tool, since you can forward declare pure Swift classes in Obj-C headers and then assign values to them from a Swift extension.